# Django-recurrence with Vuejs

Tags: django, vue.js

I am using a django backend with a vuejs frontend and I am trying to get the django-recurrence form to work inside a vue template with no luck. I am trying to generate recurrences to send to the backend. Is there a way to make this work or would I need to create my own form just for generating the recurrence field?

Answer (score 0):

django-reccurence widget relies heavily on the django templating system. The init file for the widget makes reference to django directly. If you front end is not using django, I would self bake or rely on a JS widget not tied to django.

I have not tested this with django-recurrence, but in theory you should be able to use any UI widget since the widget and django-recurrence are using the same standard.

https://github.com/collective/jquery.recurrenceinput.js/tree/master